# (New to ViewStates) What is the best way(s) to save a dynamically generated control into the viewstate?

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, controls, viewstate

I am creating a web application in Asp.net and I'm still fairly new. I'm just starting to wrap my head around the basics of the ViewState. In my application, people are searching through a database and I give them ways to narrow their search. When they have entered a valid search constraint (ex: date past 10/1/11) I dynamically add another set of controls allowing them to add another constraint. I want to save the contents of the previous constraint (a set of Controls) so that I can still have it on the webpage when they enter the next constraint.

If it makes any difference, one constraint set consists of a drop-down list of attributes, a few literal control, and one or two text fields depending on what attribute was chosen from the drop down list.

How would I go about this?

Thanks so much guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to track viewstate for dynamic controls is to recreate the controls in `OnInit` and assign the same ID to the controls every time the page is posted back. If the controls are assigned the same ID each time they're created, when the ViewState is loaded, the controls will be repopulated.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    txt.ID = "txt1";
    this.Controls.Add(txt);
}
```

**EDIT**

To make things easier, try using the DynamicControlsPlaceHolder. Just put the control on the page, and it will persist the controls and their values behind the scenes:

http://www.denisbauer.com/ASPNETControls/DynamicControlsPlaceholder.aspx

Comment: I'm attempting your solution as it seems like a fairly easy one. I'm running a problem simply saving a primitive value into the view state. In particular, I'm trying to save the integer variable count into the viewstate so I know how many dynamic controls I created.

ViewState.Add("count", count);
and
ViewState["count"] = count;

both don't seem to work. Or at least my ViewState["count"] != null always fails. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't have problems saving a value to ViewState. What issue are you running into?

Comment: It also might help to add where I'm trying to load from. I've tried loading the count value from both the Page_Init function and the Page_Load function with no success on either trial.

Comment: It doesn't seem to actually be saving. ViewState["count"] always evaluates to null. Even when I save it as ascribed in the first comment.

Comment: Through debugging I have learned the values are actually added to the ViewState variable but do not seem to persist through postbacks. Do I ever need to save the ViewState explicitly? Is there a particular place I should add key-value pairs to the ViewState structure? At the moment, I am adding to the ViewState during a button click event.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20210330142645/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/viewstate/retainingstate.aspx

ViewState for dynamic controls is still maintained by the ASP.NET framework.  Just make sure you add them during init or preinit, because viewstate is loaded for every control between the init and load stages.